# Get fields of one entity into another entity using query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to use Spring Data JPA to achieve a scenario.

I have a query that is the result of some subqueries (Ex: `select count(*) from x where id in (subquery...)`).

`X` is an entity with a table on the database. The entity to fill fields of `X` into is called `Persons`.

**Entity object**

```
@Entity
public class Persons implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long count;

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Do I need to implement something like the following?

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonssRepository extends JpaRepository<Persons, Long> {

    @Query("<my-query>")
    public long count();
}
```

Not sure how to achieve this. Any references will be a great help.

Comment: You cannot have an entity without a table... You can only use a projection/result mapping for that. So what you tried so far is simply not going to work.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using spring data jpa

Comment: Your question is unclear on what you try to achieve. Executing a sql query with a single element result is simple, it can also be mapped to an object **if** the column names match. But in that regard your question is unclear.

Comment: is 'x' mapped to an entity at all? If not, why not?

Comment: x is an entity but Persons entity is not containing any column of x's table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring JPA Projection** for this. You can find a nice tutorial by Baeldung [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections), to learn how it works.

In your case, `Persons` is your ***projection class***, so it **should not be an entity** and **should not have its own repository**.

The way projections work is through constructors of projection classes (like `Persons` class). You should create a constructor on Person with the fields you want to get in the query. Your `Persons` entity should look like this

```
public class Persons implements Serializable {

    private Long count;

    public Person(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to fetch `Persons` data from X entity, you can call the constructor of Persons to create `Persons` object from the fields of `X`. You will have the following on your `XRepository.java`:

```
@Repository
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<X, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.your.package.Persons(count(x)) FROM X x WHERE x.id in your_subquery")
    public Persons persons();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can add the formula annotation in your entity:

```
    @Formula("(SELECT count(*) FROM person_table)")
    private long count;
```

But you need a table for your entity.
Example:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_table")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2860883647884316002L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Formula("(SELECT count(*) FROM person_table)")
    private long count;
}
```

Comment: Adding Formula annotation is throwing No identifier specified for entity and including both Id & Formula annotations is throwing  Identifier property [private long count]

Comment: I guess you have a table called "person". Then you create an entity object like in my edited answer